# Matching Number Length with Prefix

Tags: powershell

I have a line in code  `<add key="Port" value="51130" />` I want to replace the value with Ports I pass in. All Start with "51" I want to be able to replace 51* essential with the new port number. I can't figure this out.

Tried something something like:

`$content = " <add key="Port" value="51130" />`

`$port = "51128"`

`(Get-Content $content).Replace("51*","$($port)")`

But I know that's literal and NOT a wildcard.

I also tried:

`(Get-Content $content).Replace('51\d+',"$($port)")`

But no luck there either.

Comment: Switch to the RegEx based `-match` **operator** `$content -replace '(?<=add key="Port" value=")\d+',$port` here $content is a **string**. I'm using a [zero length look behind assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: What if $content was a path to a text file and the key / value was a line in that file?

Comment: Then you can use `(Get-Content $content) -Replace `.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the regex replace operator, you can do the following if `$content` contains the target string.

```
$content -Replace "51\d+",$port
```

If `$content` is a path, you can run `Get-Content` and then apply `-Replace`.

```
(Get-Content $content) -Replace "51\d+",$port
```

[LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) provided the syntax for using a positive look behind assertion, which is safer for the cases where you don't want to replace all numbers in the string/file that begin with 51:

```
$content -Replace '(?<=add key="Port" value=")51\d+',$port
```

The issue with `.Replace()` is that it does not support regex. It is a method from the string class that replaces a literal string.

Also, it appears that this is part of an XML definition. You may be better served creating an XML object and updating attributes accordingly.

Comment: Converting it to an XML object is probably the smartest way to go.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that! I wasn't understanding that `.replace` was different from `-Replace`